# Is it possible to use IGP and Dedicated graphics like nvidia's optimus?

Tags: graphics-card, power-management, nvidia-geforce, optimus, igp

Pretty much like the title says. I'm curious if it would be possible to use my dedicated graphics card for gaming and other intensive tasks, while using my IGP for general usage to get power usage down?

I have an intel 3770k @ stock clock, GTX 660 Ti 2GB

Comment: On a desktop? If your motherboard happens to support [Virtu](http://lucidlogix.com/product-virtu-gpu.html), then yes.

Comment: Yes I'm on a desktop, I've got an Asrock Z77 Extreme6 Motherboard so I believe it supports Virtu. Do you have any resources I could read, or tell me how it works? Thank you for the speedy response, I didn't expect that!

Comment: Hm. You might be [in luck](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77%20Extreme6/): > Supports Intel® Smart Connect, Intel® Rapid Start, Lucid Virtu Universal MVP - You can try downloading the Virtu drivers from their drivers page. I've never used it myself (stupid P67 mobo), but it sounds like it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll take a look at it in a bit, I'm currently getting ready to reinstall windows.

Comment: There are some problems with Virtu, unfortunately. @somequixotic mentioned some of them in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11052301#11052301) (you'll need 20 rep to post there, but you can read it for now).

Comment: This is quite unlike what I was trying to do - I wasn't trying to use lucid, I was trying to use a combination of outputs from both cards. Its the same setting + software, and IIRC there's a performance hit from using lucid as well.